# How do i install puppet within a docker container? I have an Ubuntu14.04 OS

Tags: docker, puppet

I have to install puppet open source in Docker i.e create a container with a master and another with a slave.Should i create a  detached container(daemonized) that ran in the background?
I have an Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Comment: I'd suggest the guidelines on asking better questions and showing previous attempts at this.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb in docker containerization it to keep the container as lightweight as much as possible so deploying and installing stuff on containers using puppet is not recommended since you can just do the installations at the build using the Dockerfile.